# Need to remove Currency name(ie \gdp or \usd) from url in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url, currency, development

I am new to **Magento 1.9**
I m trying to remove **currency name** from **url** and at the same time setting **canonical url**

Comment: specify some more detail of issues? where you want to remove this?

Comment: remove currency name from url (https://yourwebsitename/gbp/catagoryname).but i want url like this (https://yourwebsitename/catagoryname) in magento 1.9

Comment: I think this is store code not currency.

Comment: Thanks and I am removed store code from Url using this method  "Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > No" .Now store code is removed from url.If i am changing store code means 404 not found error occur for remaining store code.How to solve this..Thank you